# Exiting Spark-shell from the scala script

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using this command to run scala scripts.

```
spark-shell -i test.scala
```

At the end of the execution of the script I still see spark-shell running.

I have used ":q/:quit" in the test.scala script to try and exit but it's not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add exit() at the end of your script to avoid stepping into scala REPL.

Helloworld.scala

```
print("Hello World");
print("Second Line");
print("Bye now");
System.exit(0)
```

Run above

```
spark-shell -i helloworld.scala
```

Comment: You may need to use `System.exit(0)`.  `exit()` did not work for me.

Comment: @dkoes Thank you for System.exit(0). exit() did not work for Spark v2.1.1

Comment: In scala you can use sys.exit(0) instead of System.exit(0)

Comment: @Jelmer i use 2.11.8 and your answer was the only one working, cheers!

Answer (score 7):

In version 2.4.3 System.exit(0) is working.

Answer (score 5):

I also like the `echo :quit | spark-shell ...` answer that was offered on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686781/execute-the-scala-script-through-spark-shell-in-silent-mode).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.