# Execute the scala script through spark-shell in silent mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

Need to execute the scala script through spark-shell with silent mode. When I am using `spark-shell -i "file.scala"`, after the execution, I am getting into the scala interactive mode. I don't want to get into there.

I have tried to execute the spark-shell -i "file.scala". But I don't know how to execute the script in silent mode.

```
spark-shell -i "file.scala"
```

after execution, I get into

```
scala>
```

I don't want to get into the `scala>` mode

### Updating (October 2019) for a script that terminates

This question is also about running a script that terminates, that is, a "scala script" that run by `spark-shell -i script.scala > output.txt` that stopts by yourself (internal instruction `System.exit(0)` terminates the script). 
See [this question with a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58513056/287948).

It also needs a *"silent mode"*, it **is expected to not pollute the `output.txt`**.

Suppose *Spark v2.2+*.

---

PS: there are a lot of cases (typically small tools and module/algorithm tests) where *Spark interpreter* can be better than *compiler*...  Please, "let's compile!" is not an answer here.

Comment: Please, cut down the repetition of content in your question, and use a spell checker in the future.

Comment: create a jar and use spark-submit instead.

Comment: REPL is not meant for this. If your `file.scala` is pure scala code then you can compile it using `scalac` and run the class file using `java` or `scala` interpreter. If it's a spark application, you can use spark-submit instead.

Answer (score 4):

`spark-shell -i file.scala` keeps the interpreter open
in the end, so `System.exit(0)` is required to be at the end of your script. The most appropriate solution is to place your code in `try {}` and put `System.exit(0)` in `finally {}` section.

If logging is requiered you can use something like this:

`spark-shell <  file.scala > test.log 2>&1 &`

If you have limitations on editing file and you can't add `System.exit(0)`, use:

`echo :quit | scala-shell -i file.scala`

***UPD***

If you want to suppress everything in output except printlns you have to turn off logging for spark-shell. The sample of configs is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-spark/26123496#26123496). Disabling any kind of logging in `$SPARK-HOME/conf/log4j.properties` should allow you to see only pritnlns. But I would not follow this approach with printlns. Using general Logging with log4j should be used instead of printlns. You can configure it so obtain the same results as with printlns. It boils down to configuring a pattern. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738244/log4j-log-only-message-string-without-logging-classname-and-other-details) provides an example of a pattern that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi. I say that use `System.exit(0)`... And  "quit" is not "quiet", the bounty is about "quiet output"...

Comment: @PeterKrauss what do u imply under "quiet"?

Comment: Hi, "to quit" by `:q`  **is not "be quiet"**. The question is about "quiet mode" (verbose=none)... Please read the question and question's bounty, *"See UPDATING 2019 section: is expected to not pollute the `output.txt`"*

Comment: @PeterKrauss you point logs to `output.txt` and want to keep only specific output?

Comment: Yes, only `println()`, no "verbose" of unsolicited outputs.

Comment: Hi Artem, you deserve the bounty for your effort and good clues, but I haven't been able to test your update ... I will probably do tests next week, or as soon as possible, then we discuss again, and I will probably edit here to include a more objective answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is definitively to compile your scala code to a jar and use `spark-submit` but if you're simply looking for a quick iteration loop, you can simply issue a `:quit` after parsing your scala code:

```
echo :quit | scala-shell -i yourfile.scala
```

Comment: There are a scala command, to use  into `yourfile.scala`, is `System.exit(0)`...  But "to quit" or "to exit" **are not "be quiet"**.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto @rluta's answer. You can place the call to `spark-shell` command inside a shell script. Say the below in a shell script:

```
spark-shell < yourfile.scala
```

But this would require you to keep the lines of code within a line in case a statement is written on different lines.

OR

```
echo :quit | spark-shell -i yourfile.scala
```

This should

Comment: Hi, "to quit" by `:q`  **is not "be quiet"**. The question is about "quiet mode" (verbose=none)... Please read the question and question's bounty, *"See UPDATING 2019 section: is expected to not pollute the `output.txt`"*