# How to count partitions with FileSystem API?

Tags: hadoop, hive, filesystems

I am using Hadoop version 2.7 and its FileSystem API. The question is about *"how to count partitions with the API?"* but, to put it into a software problem, I am coping here a Spark-Shell script... The concrete question about the script is

**The variable `parts` below is counting the number of table partitions, or other thing?**

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import spark.implicits._

val warehouse = "/apps/hive/warehouse"  // the Hive default location for all databases
val db_regex  = """\.db$""".r   // filter for names like "*.db"
val tab_regex = """\.hive\-staging_""".r    // signature of Hive files

val trStrange = "[\\s/]+|[^\\x00-\\x7F]+|[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]+|\\p{C}+".r //mark
def cutPath (thePath: String, toCut: Boolean = true) : String =
  if (toCut) trStrange.replaceAllIn( thePath.replaceAll("^.+/", ""),  "@") else thePath

val fs_get = FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration )
fs_get.listStatus( new Path(warehouse) ).foreach( lsb => {
    val b = lsb.getPath.toString
    if (db_regex.findFirstIn(b).isDefined) 
       fs_get.listStatus( new Path(b) ).foreach( lst => {
            val lstPath = lst.getPath
            val t = lstPath.toString
            var parts = -1
            var size = -1L
            if (!tab_regex.findFirstIn(t).isDefined) {
              try {
                  val pp = fs_get.listStatus( lstPath )
                  parts = pp.length // !HERE! partitions?
                  pp.foreach( p => {
                     try { // SUPPOSING that size is the number of bytes of table t
                        size  = size  + fs.getContentSummary(p.getPath).getLength
                     } catch { case _: Throwable => }
                  })
              } catch { case _: Throwable =>  }
              println(s"${cutPath(b)},${cutPath(t)},$parts,$size")
            }
        })
}) // x warehouse loop
System.exit(0)  // get out from spark-shell
```

This is only an example to show the focus: the correct scan and semantic interpretation of the *Hive default database*   FileSystem structure, using Hive FileSystem API.  The script sometimes need some memory, but is working fine. Run with 
`sshell --driver-memory 12G --executor-memory 18G -i teste_v2.scala > output.csv`

---

Note: the aim here is not to count partitions by any other method (e.g. HQL `DESCRIBE` or Spark Schema), but to use the API for it... For control and for *data quality* checks, the API is important as a kind of "lower level measurement".

Answer (score 1):

Hive structures its metadata as **database > tables > partitions > files**. This typically translates into filesystem directory structure `<hive.warehouse.dir>/database.db/table/partition/.../files`. Where `/partition/.../` signifies that tables can be partitioned by multiple columns thus creating a nested levels of subdirectories. (A **partition** is a **directory** with the name `.../partition_column=value` by convention).

So seems like your script will be printing the number of files (`parts`) and their total length (`size`) for each single-column partitioned table in each of your databases, if I'm not mistaken.

As alternative, I'd suggest you look at [`hdfs dfs -count`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count) command to see if it suits your needs, and maybe wrap it in a simple shell script to loop through the databases and tables.